# Reusing the IDbContextFactory in a console app

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor

I'm hoping someone can help a fairly new programmer.

I have a Blazor app
I have a Console app
I have a Class library

The class library contains all of the models and services for both the Blazor app and console app to access.
The Blazor app works fine, by creating the service on startup, i.e.

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<ASNDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

The blazor app uses IDbContextFactory to access the database. The services within the shared library all use this IDbContextFactory.

For example, in the shared library, I have the following method:

```
        public async Task<ReceiptHeader> GetReceiptHeadersAsync(int id)
        {
            using var context = factory.CreateDbContext();
            return await context.ReceiptHeaders.Where(p => p.Superseeded == false).FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);
        }
```

The Blazor app does this fine, as DI has populated IDbContextFactory,however I cant use IDbContextFactory from the console app as far as I can tell.

Is there a way round this, or a way to create a new dbcontext and create a DbContextFactory off of this?

I've tried to create the IDbContextFactory manually, however I get a casting issue between myDbContext and IDBContextFactory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replicate the setup or create a similar one in the console app. There are at least the following options:

1. Manually create corresponding infrastructure:

```cs
var services = new ServiceCollection();
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json") // add the rest of config sources
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();

services.AddDbContextFactory<>(...);

var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var ctxFactory = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDBContextFactory<...>>();
}
```

Do not forget to add all required packages (EF, `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`).

2. Use [generic hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host) (`Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` nuget, this approach is actually used in [worker services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers) templates):

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddDbContextFactory<>(...);
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>(); // move your app logic into hosted service
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

Comment: your first option worked perfectly. Thank you!